# How to create a FULL text index on a Computed Column

Tags: sql-server

How can I create a Full Text Index on a computed column. When I bring up the wizard for full text, it doesn't show in the list of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an index on a computed column, then it has to be PERSISTED, deterministic, precise and cannot evaluate to the image, text or ntext data types

More details - https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-indexes-on-sql-server-computed-columns/